# How to unpair or delete paired bluetooth device programmatically on android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

The project is to use my android phone to connect with my arduino devices. but how can I unpair the paired ones. I see it seems the paired list is stored where bluetoothadapter could retrieve anytime.

PS:
1st, I know long press paired device will unpair it.
but the question here is how can I make this happen programmatically?

2nd, I have checked bluetoothdevice and bluetoothAdapter class, there is no function to implement this.

thanks.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

This code works for me.

```
private void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    try {
        if (D)
            Log.d(TAG, "Start Pairing...");

        waitingForBonding = true;

        Method m = device.getClass()
            .getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
        m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);

        if (D)
            Log.d(TAG, "Pairing finished.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void unpairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    try {
        Method m = device.getClass()
            .getMethod("removeBond", (Class[]) null);
        m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ewoks, not sure what you mean

Comment: Does this works on Jelly Bean (aka 4.1.x)? Cause I am pretty sure they add new bluetooth stack and createBond method is gone..

Comment: The answer is correct but... omg... why do they keep on hiding these methods? At least, they should expose intents like for BluetoothAdapter enable/disable.

Comment: Google clearly just hates Bluetooth - this simple method has been hidden for 4 years now. They haven't even tried to implement the Out-of-Band pairing method which is the only one that isn't broken.

Comment: is there any way; without using reflection?

Comment: @DevPerfecular 
getting an exception  `parameter type is null` in unpair device , kotlin, will please mention working code for kotlin to unpair and pair device

Comment: Use this solution with extreme care Google started a depreciation program for hidden api's and the createbond method is on the greylist (use is still allowed but no guarantee until for how long): https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/pie-release/config/hiddenapi-light-greylist.txt

Comment: As of Android 9.0, this method no longer works for user-level apps due to the method now being marked as a system API, which requires system-level permissions to be invoked through reflections.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Kotlin:

```
fun removeBond(device: BluetoothDevice) {
    try {
        device::class.java.getMethod("removeBond").invoke(device)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Removing bond has been failed. ${e.message}")
    }
}
```

Or create an extension function, in this case you can use `device.removeBond()`

```
fun BluetoothDevice.removeBond() {
    try {
        javaClass.getMethod("removeBond").invoke(this)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Removing bond has been failed. ${e.message}")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

unpair all devices:

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                try {
                    Method m = device.getClass()
                            .getMethod("removeBond", (Class[]) null);
                    m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Removing has been failed.", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Isn't **removeBond()** supposed to be a public method on BluetoothDevice?  http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.java

Comment: No, it's marked with `@hide` annotation, which makes it not available to public.

Answer (score 1):

in BluetoothService class there is method removebond() to unpair , paired devices. Finally this method call rmovebondnative().

Comment: Is it a publicly-exposed api?

Answer (score -9):

If you want to delete the pair bluetooth device for this first of all you have to unpair all the device and than click on serch option you will find all device has removed from the list.