# Android how to unpair bluetooth scanner

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have an android phone and a barcode scanner. To use the scanner I pair it with the phone but in my application I want to a some point to disconnect the scanner, so to do this I thought that an unpair would be enough. I tried the accepted answer from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608140/how-to-unpair-or-delete-paired-bluetooth-device-programmatically-on-android)
but it doesn't work. Maybe the BluetoothDevice object it's not correct?

```
String mac = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getAddress();
BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(mac);
```

Actually I didn't understand what address to put in getRemoteDevice() method so I put the phone bluetooth mac address. Should I put there other address? I would appreciate any answer.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should use the address of the remote device, not your own address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once you select your scanner , you will be storing it in

```
BluetoothDevice device;
```

then just fetch the address by using device.getAddress();

and if you are calling your unpair in different activity , then just pass the address as bundle and then fetch the remote device by using:

```
BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(address);
```

I hope this will work.