# Bluetooth not getting paired

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to pair one android device with another through the bluetooth. But its not getting paired,not even getting any error. Can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong here?

I have `searched for the bluetooth` devices and **displayed that into the list**. And now I am **trying to pair the selected device name with my device**.

**But its not getting paierd,its opening a dialog for taking the password and then it gets closed.** Any help would be appreciated.
Here is my code:

```
    @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
{
Log.i("Log", "ListItem is clicked at :"+position);
posn = position;
String str = (String) listViewDetected.getItemAtPosition(position);
Log.i("Log", "ListItem is :"+str);
bluetoothDevice=arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(position);
Intent intent = new Intent("android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST");              intent.putExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.DEVICE",bluetoothDevice);       intent.putExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.PAIRING_VARIANT",0);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

I have declared the permission in the manifest file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

Comment: help me to resolve this.

Comment: pls refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989902/how-to-programmatically-pair-a-bluetooth-device-on-android & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885438/bluetooth-pairing-without-user-confirmation  this seems to happen always

Comment: I have seen but not getting any idea about this. Can you tell me how to this to achieve pairing

Comment: refer sample Bluetooth chat app available in android developers site

Comment: As per my problem, i have posted right question. But why downvoted this? Can you suggest me??

Comment: I have gone through the Bluetooth Chat application. But in that its not connection to my device.Please friends please suggest me any site through which i can pair my device programatically.

Comment: you cant actually pair your device programatically (as prior to 2.3.3 it was concidered a security flaw ) but from 2.0+ you can use unpaired rf socket to communicate. sry i dont feel sm1 can help you out in that any way try your luck

Comment: please help me out guys. or else tell me any reference to do direct connection to the unpaired devices

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer for you:

You may experiencing some Bluetooth chip errors. 
For example you tried to pair once with that device, failed for some reason, and then the chip will always decline repairing - although it shouldn't. It happened to me lots of times working with different Bluetooth Android phones...

What you can do: reset the Bluetooth chip.

Resetting the Bluetooth chip does not mean resetting your phone! While Android may be reset, the chip continues its normal lifecycle happily, and the error will reappear after reboot.

To make sure the Bluetooth chip is reset, take out the battery! On tablets, just empty the battery and restart.

If that **still** doesn't work, do a factory reset!

Bluetooth is a fragile technology, prone to bugs due to the ambiguity and vastness of its specs and the 'don't care' attitude of the chip manufacturers...

Comment: nope, I am not facing any of this kind of issue.That issue is solved simply.Now i have asked a new question regarding printing int this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/q/12257164/1395259 If you know the solution then pleaselet me know.