# How to change the font size while printing in android?

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

I am sending the text to the bluetooth printer via my android cell. Both the **printer and my device are connected via the bluetooth.**
It's Working fine and I am getting the desired text on the paper.

**My question is:**

The printer is taking the default *`font size`* of the text. I want to change the font size of the text which is to be printed.

How can i achieve this??

Here is my code of printing the text after the bloutooth connectivity:

```
private void connect_print(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevicess)  {
    // some code
    printData();
    // some code
}
```

**The printData() method**

```
private void printData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String str = new String("This is the text sending to the printer");
    String newline = "\n";
    try {
        out.write(str.getBytes(),0,str.getBytes().length);
        Log.i("Log", "One line printed");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(BluetoothDemo.this, "catch 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("Log", "unable to write ");
        flagCheck = false;
    }
    try {
        out.write(newline.getBytes(),0,newline.getBytes().length);
    } catch (IOException e) {        
        Log.i("Log", "Unable to write the new line::");
        e.printStackTrace();
        flagCheck = false;
    }
    flagCheck = true;
}
```

I want to change the `font size` and the `font style` of the text which is sending to the printer to print.
Please help me to achieve this.
If anyone can suggest any link then too i will appreciate him/her. 
**Help me to find the solution to this problem**

Comment: please suggest me what i should do at this situation?

Comment: Can anybody tell me what i have to do here

Comment: Not yet got any answer of this

Comment: Still searching for the solution. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Downvoted from long time,but still without any comment by downvoter. Anyways thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hi you write on my answer of the same theme this:

> I have already asked the same question in this thread HERE, but didnt
>   yet got any response. Got only one answer but it was not helped me.
>
> Let see whether it help you. HERE
>
> If you have done with it then please answer me in my thread. I will
>   definitely appreciate you.

*Now I konw how to do it, i had to apply reverse ingeneering and decompile an .apk from the  market, using dex2jar on linux and next opening jar with java decompiler... Try this... when u write this command:*

> `out.write(str.getBytes(),0,str.getBytes().length);`

U are sending to the method an byte[] array, u can modify format sending another byte[] array before send the real byte[] array...

The default format byte[] array is this:

> `byte[] arrayOfByte1 = { 27, 33, 0 };`

So u can try this:

> 

```
byte[] format = { 27, 33, 0 };

out.write(format);

out.write(str.getBytes(),0,str.getBytes().length);
```

These lines i'll print u the default format text, but uf u do it:

```
 byte[] format = { 27, 33, 0 };

format[2] = ((byte)(0x8 | arrayOfByte1[2]));

out.write(format);

out.write(str.getBytes(),0,str.getBytes().length);
```

It will print text in bold style... U can try this oter format arrays:

```
            // Bold
            format[2] = ((byte)(0x8 | arrayOfByte1[2]));

            // Height
            format[2] = ((byte)(0x10 | arrayOfByte1[2]));

            // Width
            format[2] = ((byte) (0x20 | arrayOfByte1[2]));

            // Underline
            format[2] = ((byte)(0x80 | arrayOfByte1[2]));

            // Small
            format[2] = ((byte)(0x1 | arrayOfByte1[2]));
```

Too u can combine it, then if u like little and bold text, uncomment these array asignements, for example:

```
 byte[] format = { 27, 33, 0 };

    // Bold
format[2] = ((byte)(0x8 | arrayOfByte1[2]));
// Height
format[2] = ((byte)(0x10 | arrayOfByte1[2]));
// Width
format[2] = ((byte) (0x20 | arrayOfByte1[2]));
// Underline
// format[2] = ((byte)(0x80 | arrayOfByte1[2]));
// Small
// format[2] = ((byte)(0x1 | arrayOfByte1[2]));
    out.write(format);
    out.write(str.getBytes(),0,str.getBytes().length);
```

This last code prints que biggest text size... I hope this can helps u...

Pdta: sorry for my english

Pdta2: **I'm trying to print images, u know how??**

Comment: Hi Narendra, thanks a lot for your code, I have been two days trying to format some text following the existing manuals and it didn't worked out. I have a problem related to this, for example: I activate BOLD mode following your suggestion, then I write a line, afterwards I go back to default style and I write another line.  
The printer will write everything just taking into account the last parameter sent, which is the default style. Did you have this problem as well?

Comment: Default style is this: `byte[] format = { 27, 33, 0 };` then you should send it to the printer before the text `out.write(format);`
`String str="my message";`
`out.write(str.getBytes(),0,str.getBytes().length);`

Comment: what's default fontSize, and how to increase fontSize?

Comment: @LeonardoSapuy 'arrayOfByte1[2]' or 'format[2]'?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you may be able to achieve this with the Java `span` method for setting up font style.

Try something like this:

```
int start=editbox.getSelectionStart();

int end=editbox.getSelectionEnd();

Spannable span=(Spannable)editbox.getText();

StyleSpan f = new StyleSpan( 
                        Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                         "fonts/genbkbasr.ttf"));

span.setSpan(f, start,end, 0);
```

Similarly, you can apply font style, font color etc...

For more detail check these:

[Android Development: How To Replace Part of an EditText with a Spannable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338697/android-development-how-to-replace-part-of-an-edittext-with-a-spannable)

[How to use SpannableString with Regex in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364119/how-to-use-spannablestring-with-regex-in-android/7365113#7365113)

Comment: Sory but this is not the solution of my question.Anyway thanks for your interest.