# How to get access to the BluetoothPairingDialog.java in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Is there any way to forcefully click on "pair button" whenever the Bluetooth pairing dialog appears?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168263/how-to-pair-bluetooth-device-programmatically-android

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to get access to the pairing dialog, but I was able to "force" pairing in the following way:

1) register a BroadcastReceiver for the action:

```
android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST
```

2) once the action is received, "force" the PIN using reflection:

```
String DEVICE_PIN = "12345";

final BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

if (intent.getAction().equals("android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_REQUEST")) {
    byte[] pin = (byte[]) BluetoothDevice.class.getMethod("convertPinToBytes", String.class).invoke(BluetoothDevice.class, ARDUINO_PIN);
    BluetoothDevice.class.getMethod("setPin", byte[].class).invoke(device, pin); 
}
```

It worked for me on GB and ICS (don't know if it works on newer releases).

Comment: I know this method but i want to know how to get access to the pairing dialog anyways thanks for the reply.