# set bluetooth authentication PIN when listening from adapter

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I'm making an app that needs to connect with a bluetooth device and get data from it... that device is set as master, so I needed to implement a `Thread`, where I `listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord` and wait for a connection from it:

```
    public AcceptThread(Context context, String serverName, UUID myUUID) {
    this.context = context;
    BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    try {

        // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the client code
        tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(serverName, myUUID);
    } catch (IOException e) { }
    mmServerSocket = tmp;
}
```

Then on `run` I run the code `socket = mmServerSocket.accept(5000)` to wait until it starts pairing with the device:

```
    public void run() {
    BluetoothSocket socket = null;
    while (true) {
        try {
            socket = mmServerSocket.accept(5000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"IOException: " + e);
        }

        // If a connection was accepted
        if (socket != null) {

            // Manage the connection
            ManageConnectedSocket manageConnectedSocket = new ManageConnectedSocket(socket);
            manageConnectedSocket.run();

            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The Device asks for an authentication PIN, and I need to have an automatic procedure... for that I though of implementing a broadcast receiver to know when the device is asked to par with another device:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST);
context.registerReceiver(mPairReceiver, filter);
```

and receive it:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mPairReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST.equals(action)) {
            Log.e(TAG,"ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST");
            setBluetoothPairingPin(device);
        }
    }
};
```

In my `setBluetoothPairingPin` method I receive a `BluetoothDevice` object :

```
public void setBluetoothPairingPin(BluetoothDevice device) {
    byte[] pinBytes = convertPinToBytes("0000");
    try {
        Log.e(TAG, "Try to set the PIN");
        Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("setPin", byte[].class);
        m.invoke(device, pinBytes);
        Log.e(TAG, "Success to add the PIN.");
        try {
            device.getClass().getMethod("setPairingConfirmation", boolean.class).invoke(device, false);
            Log.e(TAG, "Success to setPairingConfirmation.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The problem is that I can't know when my socket receives information, and consecutively, can't know what is my `BluetoothDevice` to set Pairing Pin before it's connected...
Can someone help me on how to surpass this? Or is there other way to put the pin authentication when I'm listenning from `BluetoothServerSocket`?

If I'm not explaining correctly, please let me know...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use Push Button Configuration instead of entering pin. You will just need to click on Pair button and not enter a pin. Does this help?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. not really...
I do not control the other device requirements, it asks for a pin confirmation and it's set has master. So in order for me to connect I need to listen to the device, but I also need to insert a pin when I'll connect with it... any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510891/how-to-get-access-to-the-bluetoothpairingdialog-java-in-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047995/programmatically-pair-bluetooth-device-without-the-user-entering-pin), I was able to make work for me...

My confusion was with the method `setBluetoothPairingPin` that I couldn't understand that the `ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST` is actually called when the device is being starting to pairing, and that is when the PIN is asked from the user... so invoking `BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);`, and changing a bit of the set pairing method I manage to make it work...

Here's my final code:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
    if (ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                String PIN = "0000";

                byte[] pin = new byte[0];
                try {
                    pin = (byte[]) BluetoothDevice.class.getMethod("convertPinToBytes", String.class).invoke(BluetoothDevice.class, PIN);
                    BluetoothDevice.class.getMethod("setPin", byte[].class).invoke(device, pin);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }
}
```