# Paring two bluetooth devices: createbond() or connect()

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am currently using connect() to pair my android phone to a bluetooth device. If it's the first time I do it, it asks me to enter the PIN number.
However, I saw there was a fonction called createbond() useful to pair devices, but only from API 19 and later.

There is my question: how to pair devices, without connecting, and from API 14 and later?
Or do I misuse/misunderstand these functions?

Thanks

Comment: You must first connect to pair devices, so you can only pair with connecting the devices, but if you only want to pair the devices, connect them and after they paired make a disconnect/close socket

Comment: Thanks, but if I want to avoid connecting each time I want to

Comment: ok, i think this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168263/how-to-pair-bluetooth-device-programmatically-android) could help you