# Ionic Android pairing with Bluetooth without PIN

Tags: ionic-framework

I am working with Arduino and a bluetooth module (specifically HC-05 and HC-06). I have a Ionic app that uses the [Bluetooth Serial plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/bluetooth-serial/) and I can connect to the bluetooth module successfully, however I want to be able to remove the pop up that appears asking the user to enter the PIN to pair my Android to the Bluetooth module. I know this can be done using native SDK, [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35519321/android-bluetooth-pairing-without-user-enter-pin-and-confirmation-using-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168263/how-to-pair-bluetooth-device-programmatically-android?rq=1). But not sure how I would go about it using Ionic.

Comment: any update on this?