# iPhone Bluetooth pairing without confirming passcode

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, pairing

In my BLE app, the user story is like, bluetooth pairing should happen without the passcode confirmation step. As far as i have researched so far, it is possible in Android (like [Android Bluetooth Pairing without User Enter Pin and Confirmation Using Android API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35519321/android-bluetooth-pairing-without-user-enter-pin-and-confirmation-using-android))

Is it possible in iPhone?

Comment: Yes, but the user still needs to confirm OK in a popup.

Answer (score 1):

There are three types of connection in BLE:

- connection: pin not required, connection not secure
- pair: pin could be requested or not, connection secured with short term key, a popup will be displayed
- bond: pin could be requested or not, connection secured with long term
  key, a popup will be displayed

All of these method are managed by BLE peripheral firmware, iOS only adapts its connection based on how the peripheral is configured

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, on iOS it is not possible to skip the pairing dialog. It is directly sent from the OS. It is a strict convention from apple that apps are not able to skip security processes.

Some additional information:

Dependent on the IOCapabilityResponse from the peripheral device on bluetooth level iOS will show you a dialog asking to pair or to confirm a pass code. If iOS will show you the dialog at all depends if the bondable flag is set in the IOCapabilityResponse from the peripheral.