# Automatically pairing 2 BlueTooth devices

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, pairing

I know this question has already been asked but It does not work for me. I want to automatically pair 2 devices without having a pairing notification on my device. I followed the instruction here: [How to pair Bluetooth device programmatically Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168263/how-to-pair-bluetooth-device-programmatically-android) but it does not work. Indeed, I still have a pairing notification.
Here is my code:

```
IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST);
    final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver2 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    int pin=intent.getIntExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.PAIRING_KEY", 0);
                    byte[]  pinBytes = Integer.toString(pin).getBytes();
                    device.setPin(pinBytes);
                    boolean b = device.createBond();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(mReceiver2, filter2);
```

Comment: On what version(s) of Android do you have this issue?

Comment: I have this issue on 2 (very) different version of Android: KitKat and Oreo (4 and 8)