# Android - How add bluetooth device to paired programically?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, bluetooth

I have Android app(xamarin). I working with bluetooth device. But it work when bluetooth device is "paired devices". I can find available devices. I need change my bluetooth device from "available device" to "paired devices" programmatically.

Is it possible? Any advices.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pair Bluetooth device programmatically Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168263/how-to-pair-bluetooth-device-programmatically-android)

Comment: Also checkout the android documentation on bluetooth if you haven't already https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth