# Can any BLE device be a Companion Device?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt, pairing, android-companion-device

I'm developing a flutter application (fairly new to this).

My app need to connect to a BLE device and get data when it is close by. As I found Android **Companion Device Manage** seems to suit my requirement. BLE Hardware which I'm supposed to work is still under development(firmware) and I'm trying to test above using available hardware(a heart rate censor) without a success.

I have a couple of questions.


1. Can I use **any BLE device as a Companion Device**? or

Does device firmware need to support it?

2. Should I must use **secure connection (enter pin) using device.createBond()**? or

Can I use **Just Work using device.connectGatt()**?

3. Assuming if this work in Android, **is there a Companion Device equivalent in iOS**?

After going through the official document https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/companion-device-pairing

 and [How to pair Bluetooth device programmatically Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168263/how-to-pair-bluetooth-device-programmatically-android) below is my implementation.

```
public final var SELECT_DEVICE_REQUEST_CODE:Int = 12
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val pairingRequestFilter = IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED)
    pairingRequestFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST)
    registerReceiver(pairingReceiver, pairingRequestFilter)

    // To skip filters based on names and supported feature flags (UUIDs),
    // omit calls to setNamePattern() and addServiceUuid()
    // respectively, as shown in the following  Bluetooth example.
    val deviceFilter: BluetoothDeviceFilter = BluetoothDeviceFilter.Builder()
        .setNamePattern(Pattern.compile("two"))
        .build()

    // The argument provided in setSingleDevice() determines whether a single
    // device name or a list of them appears.
    val pairingRequest: AssociationRequest = AssociationRequest.Builder()
        .addDeviceFilter(deviceFilter)
        .setSingleDevice(true)
        .build()

    // When the app tries to pair with a Bluetooth device, show the
    // corresponding dialog box to the user.
    deviceManager.associate(pairingRequest,
        object : CompanionDeviceManager.Callback() {

            override fun onDeviceFound(chooserLauncher: IntentSender) {
                startIntentSenderForResult(chooserLauncher,
                    SELECT_DEVICE_REQUEST_CODE, null, 0, 0, 0)
            }

            override fun onFailure(error: CharSequence?) {
                // Handle the failure.
            }
        }, null)
}
```

This is how call device.createBond()

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    when (requestCode) {
        SELECT_DEVICE_REQUEST_CODE -> when(resultCode) {
            Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
                // The user chose to pair the app with a Bluetooth device.
                val deviceToPair: BluetoothDevice? =
                    data?.getParcelableExtra(CompanionDeviceManager.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                deviceToPair?.let { device ->
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                                this,
                                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
                            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        ) {
                            return
                        }
                    }

                    device.createBond()

                    // Maintain continuous interaction with a paired device.

                }
            }
        }
        else -> super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}
```

I tried to do device.setPin() as follows. But always end up with BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE

```
private var pairingReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val action = intent!!.action
        Log.d("BRC: BLE ",action.toString())

        val device: BluetoothDevice? =intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
        PAIRING_PIN =intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PAIRING_KEY, BluetoothDevice.ERROR)
        val pin = intent.getIntExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.PAIRING_KEY", 0)

        when (action) {
            BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST -> {
                val type =intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PAIRING_VARIANT, BluetoothDevice.ERROR)

                if (type == BluetoothDevice.PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                                getContext(),
                                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
                            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        ) {
                            return
                        }
                    }
                    device?.setPin("0".toByteArray(charset("UTF-8")))
                    //setPairing confirmation if neeeded
                }else if (type == BluetoothDevice.PAIRING_VARIANT_PASSKEY_CONFIRMATION) {
                    Log.d("TAG","BLE device PAIRING_VARIANT_PASSKEY_CONFIRMATION-${device?.bondState}")
                }

            }
            BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED -> {
                val type =intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE, BluetoothDevice.ERROR)
                if (type == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                    Log.d("TAG:","BLE device BOND_BONDING-${device?.bondState}")
                }else if (type == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    Log.d("TAG:","BLE device BOND_BONDED-${device?.bondState}")
                }else if (type == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE) {
                    Log.d("TAG:","BLE device BOND_NONE-${device?.bondState}") //★Always end up in here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Can I use any BLE device as a Companion Device? or
>    Does device firmware need to support it?

Technically if your device can do BLE advertising, then you should be able to use CompanionDeviceManager to associate with your device.

> 2. Should I must use secure connection (enter pin) using device.createBond()? or
>    Can I use Just Work using device.connectGatt()?

See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/connect-bluetooth-devices#connection-techniques. `If the two devices have not been previously paired, then the Android framework automatically shows a pairing request notification or dialog to the user during the connection procedure, as shown in figure 1.`

> 3. Assuming if this work in Android, is there a Companion Device equivalent in iOS?

I'm not familiar with iOS, sorry I can't help here.