# How can I set up that opened bluetooth pairing dialog everytime

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've made bluetooth app of Android.

The bluetooth's connecting and disconnecting function is not working , and Users can't pair their devices.

I want to open bluetooth pairing dialog whenever it's not connected.

Bluetooth 4.0 SmartPhone's android Version s 4.3 and later

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How to pair bluetooth devices programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834318/android-how-to-pair-bluetooth-devices-programmatically)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834318/android-how-to-pair-bluetooth-devices-programmatically