# Disconnecting and reconnecting bluetooth

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

Activity 1: I have enabled bluetooth and paired it with a device automatically. Now I'm navigating to activity 2 via a button click

Activity 2: I have a button in Activity 2 which will navigate back to activity 1 with an added flag via Putextra to disconnect bluetooth

Activity 1: Now i should disconnect and reconnect bluetooth if that flag exist.

I have received flag from intent but puzzled on how to disconnect existing bluetooth connection and reconnect. Any help would be grateful.

Comment: can you show me some of ur related code stuff ? and refer this first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834318/android-how-to-pair-bluetooth-devices-programmatically for pair and unpair device programmatically .

Comment: I don't want to unpair, I just need to disconnect and reconnect, Any idea on that?