# Android forces Bluetooth LE connection when call createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am developing an app to control a custom device. This custom device has a dual mode bluetooth and working in dual mode function for accepting Android and iOS connections.

With Android I need use classic connection. I made some tests with several smartphones and tablets. However, with some tablets models I am have problem to connect.

I have a tablet with MT6572 SOC from MediaTek and it has 4.4.2 android. I also have a SAMSUNG Galaxy Tab E with SC8830 SOC from Spreadtrum and it has 4.4.4 android. Both tablets has API level 19.

I get the adapter this way :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
       if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
            mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
            if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    }
```

And to connect I code this way:

```
BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

BluetoothSocket socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID); 
socket.connect()
```

The socket is created successfully, but when I try to connect I receive the following error/message:

> java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1

When I observe the log from my custom device with dual mode bluetooth I see events from a Low Energy connection. It seem that Android is not respecting my attempt of creating socket and classic bluetooth connection.

Is behavior normal this? can be a bug in android?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if device is discoverable using `mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()`,[javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startDiscovery())
2. Check if you paired a custom device with Android device. You also can do this manually. [How to pair bluetooth devices programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834318/android-how-to-pair-bluetooth-devices-programmatically)
3. Do the connect via [createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(java.util.UUID))

This approach works for me in many cases.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am using this approach too. The samsung tablet worked like a charm, my tests were wrong. But the MT6572 SOC did not work, I am thinking that there is a bug inside of the bluetooth stack.