# How to send file / message between two android device with out any intermediate server

Tags: android, networking, network-programming, google-cloud-messaging, android-internet

I want to send files between two devices using internet connection with out use any intermediate /server. For example  there are two device A and B  both have internet connection and both device have installed my application, now need to send a file from Device A to Device B. Device A can know all the detail about the Device B.

Is this possible means guide me in the correct way.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Peer to Peer architecture to achieve this. Basically every phone is a client and a server the same time. See [here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/) for a basic implementation.

If the internet is not a prerequisite, you can follow Minav Patel's suggestion and use the Android Bluetooth implementation.

Another solution would be the WiFi-Direct feature (if the phone support it). See [here](http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/android-wifi-direct-tutorial.30409/) for an example.

Comment: Thank you checked link for peer to peer connection it helps me lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement file transfer between two android devices using android bluetooth implementation.Go through following links it will help

[android bluetooth implementation basics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372375/android-bluetooth-implementation-basics)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html