# android instant message application

Tags: android, messaging

i am pretty new to android, but there is something that i really want to build and i really need some advice of how and what i should be looking into.

it is basically gonna be an instant message app for android, it is an app that only works for 2 person. person A and person B, they will have to connect to each other phone somehow ( i assume using some unique ID ?), and there will be a widget on their phone. When person A press the button, person B will receive a random message that pops up on person B's phone and also vibrate on person B's phone. and when person B press it again as an reply, it will do the same to person A's phone.

what kind of library or concept should i be looking into for this kinda app?

thanks

Comment: thanks for the advice, i am wondering what is the best way to connect b/w 2 phones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/

> The idea involves Socket Programming and basically letting one phone be the “server” and the other phone be the “client”. Now, I don’t know if this is standard practice for letting two phones communicate with one another, but it worked for me in a new application that I’ve been working on, and so here it is:
>   public class ServerActivity extends Activity {

```
private TextView serverStatus;

// DEFAULT IP
public static String SERVERIP = "10.0.2.15";

// DESIGNATE A PORT
public static final int SERVERPORT = 8080;

private Handler handler = new Handler();

private ServerSocket serverSocket;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.server);
    serverStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.server_status);

    SERVERIP = getLocalIpAddress();

    Thread fst = new Thread(new ServerThread());
    fst.start();
}

public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        try {
            if (SERVERIP != null) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.setText("Listening on IP: " + SERVERIP);
                    }
                });
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
                while (true) {
                    // LISTEN FOR INCOMING CLIENTS
                    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            serverStatus.setText("Connected.");
                        }
                    });

                    try {
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                            Log.d("ServerActivity", line);
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT TO THE FRONT END
                                    // THIS IS WHERE YOU CAN BE CREATIVE
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        break;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                serverStatus.setText("Oops. Connection interrupted. Please reconnect your phones.");
                            }
                        });
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.setText("Couldn't detect internet connection.");
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    serverStatus.setText("Error");
                }
            });
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

// GETS THE IP ADDRESS OF YOUR PHONE'S NETWORK
private String getLocalIpAddress() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) { return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString(); }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e("ServerActivity", ex.toString());
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {
         // MAKE SURE YOU CLOSE THE SOCKET UPON EXITING
         serverSocket.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}

}
```

You will have a client and a server. Server sends to client. Because both phones are sending to eachother, the client and server will be constantly switching. You can also try using bluetooth implementation:

[android bluetooth implementation basics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372375/android-bluetooth-implementation-basics)

There are many ways to do networking, and you should look into that. But, to vibrate the phone, like you said you wanted, just use the following code:

```
import android.os.Vibrator;
 ...
 Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
 // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
 v.vibrate(500);
```

And you will need this permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Let me know if this helped!

:-)

Comment: thanks alot for the info, it will take me sometimes to get though all these, i will let you know if i have any problems with ur code tho. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a moblie cloud to do it. Ex: Google Cloud Message, Parse,...
those are replace a webserver to receive message, process them and send to other.
I recommend use Parse: https://parse.com/ (using Push notification function)  . It also support Geopoint, store file, send message,...

Comment: parse looks pretty cool, i will need some time to read them all one by one, but thanks for the advices