# Is there a way to isolate and control the Bluetooth pairing process programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

My applications connects my Android phone to a health device. The health device is capable of connecting using either Bluetooth SPP or HDP profile while my app can only support SPP.

The health device's documentation states that I have to send a special command to the it during the pairing process to make sure that Bluetooth communication uses SPP profile instead of HDP.

Note that I'm not concerned about connection after pairing at all. I need to:

1. Separate the pairing process from the connections after pairing - I don't mind if users have to authorise pairing through a popup
2. Be able to send some data to the health device during the pairing process (so that following connections will actually happen)

[The Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) seems to imply that pairing is implicitly handled as an integrated part of the Bluetooth connections as you call `connect()` or `accept()`. However, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337032/how-can-i-avoid-or-dismiss-androids-bluetooth-pairing-notification-when-i-am-do) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989902/how-to-programmatically-pair-a-bluetooth-device-on-android) gives me some hope.

I'd like to support as many devices as possible but 4.0 and above are more important. The health device I'm using supports Bluetooth 2.1 so no worries about PIN.