# Android: hide pairing dialog

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm new to android and trying to programmatically connect a BluetoothDevice. Device has a PIN. Connecting to device is in another thread than UI. So far I have followed example from [How to programmatically pair a bluetooth device on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989902/how-to-programmatically-pair-a-bluetooth-device-on-android).

On **BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST** I convert String to byte[] and do a setPin call. the pairing dialog pops out and dissapear. Any actions like

> ```
>        Method createBondMethod1 = device.getClass().getMethod("cancelPairingUserInput");  
>        Boolean returnValue2 = (Boolean) createBondMethod1.invoke(device);
> ```

have failed on setPin. **BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST** is triggered when device.createBond() is called.

The question is how can I hide Pairing dialog?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I've found is to dimiss all system dialogs by using:

```
    getContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS));
```

But the problem is to capture the right moment to dimiss it, and the trusted solution to this problem has to be to not show that dialog,... but I think the only solution to that will could on modifying the bluetoothDialog apk in the system for not showing that intent.

If anyone knows a better solution, please let us know!