# How to know when bluetooth pairing completed

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to listen for incoming messages through bluetooth when pairing totally completed. I can't call listen(can I?) before the pairing is completed and I can't know when it is completed.

I tried a lot of methods to pair between two devices like this one:

```
   private void pairDevice() {
    try {
        BluetoothDevice device = bluetooth.getRemoteDevice(address);
        Log.d("pairDevice()", "Start Pairing...");
        Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
        m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
        Log.d("pairDevice()", "Pairing finished.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("pairDevice()", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

this one works nice but it opens a popup to accept the pairing and the`Log.d("pairDevice()", "Pairing finished.");` is called before the popup dialog is being accepted and I need to do things only when the pairing is totally completed and the devices are now paired. here is my code for listening for messages:

```
public void run() {
    final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bytes = 0;
    int b = BUFFER_SIZE;
    while (true) {
        try {
            bytes = inStream.read(buffer, bytes, BUFFER_SIZE - bytes);
            textview.setText(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

here is my code for sending the message(score):

```
  private void init() throws IOException {
    if (bluetooth != null) {
        if (bluetooth.isEnabled()) {
            Set<BluetoothDevice> bondedDevices = bluetooth.getBondedDevices();
            if (bondedDevices.size() > 0) {
                ParcelUuid[] uuids = device.getUuids();
                BluetoothSocket socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuids[0].getUuid());
                socket.connect();
                outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                inStream = socket.getInputStream();
                write(score);
            }
            Log.e("error", "No appropriate paired devices.");
        } else {
            Log.e("error", "Bluetooth is disabled.");
        }
    }
}

public void write(String s) throws IOException {
    outputStream.write(s.getBytes());
}
```

I tried to pair two devices without user permission like in this answer -[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22201805/3784668)- but it also asked for permissions i don't know why .. So actually I don't think I need pairing without permission I just need doing something when popup accepted. is it possible? thanks.

Comment: Maybe this link helps you  >>>>>>   [How to programmatically tell if a Bluetooth device is connected? (Android 2.2)][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715865/how-to-programmatically-tell-if-a-bluetooth-device-is-connected-android-2-2

Comment: @ASHKARAN i will try it later when I will recieve my computer back. Thx

Comment: @ASHKARAN  it also happens only when popup appears.